# Cannot get UPS extension to work with One Page Checkout Virtuemart 2, Joomla 2.5

Tags: plugins, joomla, module, virtuemart, ups

I cannot get UPS extension to work with the One Page Checkout extension.

I'm using Virtuemart 2 & Joomla 2.5

http://www.mackeyshotrods.com/test/store

When I enter my address at the checkout screen it says

"We are sorry, no shipment method matches the characteristics of your order."

I tried making my own shipping method and it worked fine so it has to do with either the

ups plugin or One Page checkout.

Please help

Comment: Why not try contacting the extension developer?

Comment: Which extension are you using for UPS ? from http://extensions.virtuemart.net/ site ? Then they will support to fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

Yes one page checkout process is really great and lowers the time and efforts of the costumers by bringing all the details of the checkout process on one page. If this not working then you can checkout the VMCheckout plugin it is really good and works well. Here is the link to the site.
http://www.vmcheckout.com